I am having an issue with replaceAll in MongoDB
I'm trying to append the text "[retrying: " + time.Now().Format("15:04") + "]" in such a way that if it is missing in the field, it will be added; if it is present, it will be replaced.
For example (adding text):
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "66f134e7ad3dc5c40ced7b2a"
  },
  "CreatedAt": {
    "$date": "2024-09-23T09:29:11.276Z"
  },
  "UpdatedAt": {
    "$date": "2024-09-24T22:15:50.679Z"
  },
  "Step": "Waiting to receive information from the network"
}

Target:
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "66f134e7ad3dc5c40ced7b2a"
  },
  "CreatedAt": {
    "$date": "2024-09-23T09:29:11.276Z"
  },
  "UpdatedAt": {
    "$date": "2024-09-24T22:15:50.679Z"
  },
  "Step": "Waiting to receive information from the network [retrying 12:00]"
}

Or (replacing text)
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "66f134e7ad3dc5c40ced7b2a"
  },
  "CreatedAt": {
    "$date": "2024-09-23T09:29:11.276Z"
  },
  "UpdatedAt": {
    "$date": "2024-09-24T22:15:50.679Z"
  },
  "Step": "Waiting to receive information from the network [retrying 12:00]"
}

Target:
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "66f134e7ad3dc5c40ced7b2a"
  },
  "CreatedAt": {
    "$date": "2024-09-23T09:29:11.276Z"
  },
  "UpdatedAt": {
    "$date": "2024-09-24T22:15:50.679Z"
  },
  "Step": "Waiting to receive information from the network [retrying 12:05]"
}

Currently I have this code that I am trying with:
fieldName := "$Step" 
retryingRegex := `\s\[retrying:.*\]`
retryingInfo := " [retrying: " + time.Now().Format("15:04") + "]"
update := bson.A{
    bson.M{
        "$set": bson.M{
            "Step": bson.M{
                "$cond": bson.M{
                    "if": bson.M{
                        "$regexMatch": bson.M{
                            "input": fieldName,
                            "regex": retryingRegex,
                        },
                    },
                    "then": bson.M{
                        "$replaceAll": bson.M{
                            "input":       fieldName,
                            "find":        retryingRegex,
                            "replacement": retryingInfo,
                        },
                    },
                    "else": bson.M{
                        "$concat": []string{
                            fieldName,
                            retryingInfo,
                        },
                    },
                },
            },
        },
    },
}
filter := bson.M{"_id": id}
collection.UpdateOne(ctx, filter, update)

But it doesn't seems to work.
DB version v7.0.8
Go version 1.22

What does "it doesn't seems to work" mean? Error? No error? Silently not doing anything? Doing something wrong? Also note that UpdateOne() returns an error. I hope you're checking it your real code.

Getting MatchedCount 1,ModifiedCount 0 and error nil

The problem is that in the $replaceAll operation the find field must be a "plain" string to find (and replace). It can't be a regular expression (more precisely it's not used as a regular expression).
What you may do is execute a $regexFind to find the part that occurs in the value of the updatable Step field, and replace that.
But $regexpFind doesn't return the matching substring, it returns an object whose match field contains the matching substring. To get its match field, you may use $getField.
This is how it may look like (only the "then" branch, the rest is unchanged and omitted for brevity):
"then": bson.M{
    "$replaceAll": bson.M{
        "input": fieldName,
        "find": bson.M{
            "$getField": bson.M{
                "field": "match",
                "input": bson.M{
                    "$regexFind": bson.M{
                        "input": fieldName,
                        "regex": retryingRegex,
                    },
                },
            },
        },
        "replacement": retryingInfo,
    },
},

Note that personally I would just store retryingInfo in a separate field, which would result in much simpler and cleaner code. Even that formatting is unnecessary, just store the timestamp, and it can be formatted when displayed to the user.
